# Server Logs in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, session

How to find session logs of the servers connected to SQL Developer, and also I need to see what statements that server is executing, I have used this,

```
select   sess.sid,
         sess.serial#,
         sess.username,
         sql_text
from 
v$sqlarea sqlarea, 
v$session sess
where sess.prev_hash_value = sqlarea.hash_value
and sess.prev_sql_addr  = sqlarea.address
and sess.username = <con_name>
```

but still I'm not getting the server logs

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. However, the community does expect a certain quality in the questions posted. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_. Currently your question is missing a full explanation (missing details) and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/218486/edit) your question and add more details. (e.g. what server logs?)

Comment: Servers don't "connect to SQL Developer" - SQL clients like SQL Developer connect **to** an Oracle server.

Comment: your query - what are you not getting that you are expecting? there are actual server logs like the Alert log that you can query, but what you are looking at are live/as-is-right now data dictionary views for activity in the database

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off starting with one of the included Reports.

SQL*Developer comes with a Report for Alert logs (11g+) and various Reports for Sessions.

To access the list of reports: View -> Reports

[image: List of relevant Reports that come with SQL*Developer]

If you don't like the provided Reports, feel free to make your own.

For SQL*Developer tips and tricks, I recommend [this site](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/sql-developer/).

Comment: I have connected TIBCO Studio with SQL Developer, that is data is being fetched in TIBCO Studio from SQL Developer. Now when i execute any sql statement in TIBCO Studio i want to see its log in SQL Developer, that is how that sql statement is been executed, with what parameters in SQL Developer, V$SESSION in my query gives only the session details but i need log details, how my statement executing in TIBCO is being run in SQL Developer.

Comment: @PremAcharya -  `TIBCO Studio` is an Oracle Client (assumption). `SQL*Developer` is an Oracle Client.  You can't connect a client to a client.  If `TIBCO Studio` is producing Logs, you'll have to look at `TIBCO Studio` for the Logs (eg Error Logs, Debug Logs, etc).  If you want to see the SQL Statement being used by `TIBCO Studio` and the associated Explain Plan for that SQL statement, from within `SQL*Developer`, you should use the Report `All Reports -> Data Dictionary Reports -> Sessions -> Sessions`.  You will need DBA like privileges to see all the information.

Comment: TIBCO Studio is not an Oracle Client, rather it is a Java SQL client like SQuirellSQL etc.